# SharePoint List connections left outer join

Tags: excel, sharepoint, odbc, powerpivot

I have a connection to SharePoint manly in 2 Lists

**Corporations, Corporations Products**

I'm using Power Pivot in order to apply some filters. The main problem, and as required, I have to include all corporations even if don't have products, that means only the Corporations that have Products are listed.

So I don't know if this is a constraint (AS IS) or if there is some kind of solution, or idea, that's because I kindly ask help to the community.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Power Pivot it's not what I do best, so this are my conclusions to solve the issue

1. All 1:2 connections bring all information required as left outer join.
2. To solve the issue I had to force a no sense count in order to companies without products can be presented in my pivot. After I hide the count from the Excel file and goal could be accomplished.